# beforeunload safari iframe issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

**sample.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};

</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> Yahoo</a> </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="sample.html" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

so the issue is when I am clicking on yahoo link onbeforeunload function is not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution for Iframe

I got the iFrame object in iFrameObject variable then used following command it worked in safari 3.1.1 and other browsers too

iframeObject.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

Answer (score 0):

since you havn't given very much information, i can only guess whats your problem and show you the working possibility for a cross-browser unload-message taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

if you're doing something different, try this - if it srill doesn't work, please add some code. how should anyone know whats wrong with your code without seeing it?

Comment: I have provided the code and more information for your reference.Please take a look..